# javascript eventElement.resizable is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have looked around and although I have found similar questions to this one, none of them had any solutions that worked for me.

my fullcalendar.js gets an error : eventElement.resizable is not a function

```
function resizableSlotEvent(event, eventElement, timeElement) {
    var snapDelta, prevSnapDelta;
    var snapHeight = getSnapHeight();
    var snapMinutes = getSnapMinutes();
    eventElement.resizable({             <----get error
        handles: {
            s: '.ui-resizable-handle'
        },
     ...
```

my html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>

<link href='{% static "css/fullcalendar.css" %}' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='{% static "css/fullcalendar.print.css" %}' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />


<!-- JS-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>


<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/fullcalendar.js'%}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
```

I tried a lot of answers of stackoverflow. But I can't solved the problem. Anyone help?

Comment: Show how you call `resizableSlotEvent()` , particularly what `eventElement` is

Answer (score 0):

That custom jqueryui js doesn't seem to include the resizable plugin, and the code you're showing relies on it.

Try it with the full js of a recent jQuery ui instead.